# Query does not found column, suggests same column in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, rank

I have the following query in SQL:

```
select midquery.account, midquery.name, midquery.label,  midquery.labelfrequency
from(

    -- Count the appearance of each label.

    select count(*) as labelfrequency, account, name, label
    from(

        select account, name, label from myTable 

    ) innerquery

    group by account, name, label
) midquery

-- Select most frequent values only.
where rank() over 
    (partition by midquery.account, midquery.name 
     order by midquery.labelfrequency desc) = 1
```

The idea is to find the most frequent label per name-account set. When I run this query, I get the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10002]: Line 12:74 Invalid column reference 'labelfrequency': (possible column names are: labelfrequency, account, name, label)
```

I don't quite understand why the interpreter does not find the column labelfrequency but can suggest it. Have you got any suggestions on how to tackle this issue?

**Edit:** if I move the rank() to the select part, I get results.

```
select midquery.account, midquery.name, midquery.label,  midquery.labelfrequency, 
    rank() over (partition by midquery.account, midquery.name 
     order by midquery.labelfrequency desc)
from(

    -- Count the appearance of each label.

    select count(*) as labelfrequency, account, name, label
    from(

        select account, name, label from myTable 

    ) innerquery

    group by account, name, label
) midquery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window functions are simply not allowed in the `WHERE` clause.  There are good reasons for this, but you can think of it as just another rule of SQL --  similar to column aliases not being recognized.

(The real reason is specifying how the window function would operate when there are multiple filtering conditions.  It is (almost ?) impossible to come up with a coherent set of rules.)

Having said that, you can simplify your query:

```
select t.account, t.name, t.label, t.labelfrequency
from (select count(*) as labelfrequency, account, name, label,
             rank() over (partition by account, name
                          order by count(*) desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from myTable t
      group by account, name, label
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

That is, window functions and aggregation functions can be combined.  And you don't need a subquery to specify only a handful a columns.